# IOS String issues. one works, one doesn't, what gives?

Tags: ios, nsstring

from the .h

```
NSString *_maplink;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mapLink;
```

in the .m

this one is fine

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,+%f&daddr=thatCity+thatState+515+north+state+street", latitude, longitude];
```

i need the property later so i'm

```
mapLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,+%f&daddr=thatCity+thatState+515+north+state+street", latitude, longitude];
```

then i

```
NSLog(@"the map link %@", mapLink);
```

in a different function and I get the ole SIGABRT.

what's the dilly o?

Comment: On the line that begins `mapLink = [NSString ...`, should that be `_mapLink`?

Comment: yes just figured that out, should have checked back earlier, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assigning your string to the `mapLink` variable won't retain it. You need to:

```
self.mapLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,+%f&daddr=thatCity+thatState+515+north+state+street", latitude, longitude];
```

Comment: Nice. I like this syntax better than what I had above. the whole issue was not synthesizing the property correctly i had `@synthesize mapLink;` instead of `@synthesize mapLink = _mapLink;` as @jlehr had mentioned above.